# How to disable the reordering of table columns in tableView?

Tags: tableview, javafx-2

Trying to figure out on how can i disable the reordering of table columns in javafx 2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
tblView.getColumns().addListener(new ListChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change change) {
          change.next();
          if(change.wasReplaced()) {
              tblView.getColumns().clear();
              tblView.getColumns().addAll(column1,column2...);
          }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think there should be some way to disable the column reordering behaviour via an API on the `TableView` class, you might want to also log a feature request against the [JavaFX runtime project](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com).

Comment: @jewelsea So, it's been 1 year, any sign of an improved API method to lock the columns ?

Comment: Feature request [RT-26283 "Support "locking" columns (and rows) in TableView"](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-26283) was created.  There has been no progress made on it and the request is currently not scheduled.  The feature request was accepted, so a [patch request to openjfx](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX) to add the feature would probably be accepted.

Comment: thats not a solution to just delete every column and add them again.

Answer (score 3):

After much waste of time, I've found the following, very simple, solution:

```
TableHeaderRow header = (TableHeaderRow) myTableView.lookup("TableHeaderRow");
header.setMouseTransparent(true);
```

Comment: Like a charm in Java 8.