# Javafx: bind Hbox spacing?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, bind, spacing

I have a `TableView` and a `Hbox` below the table, in the hBox there are three`Label`s one contains a text, and two contains the sum of two columns in the table. I want to set a spacing somehow dynamic for the HBox to align the two labels exactly below the two columns in the table to which they belong. Is there any possibility to bind the `HBox`'s spacing to the columns position. 
I also accept any other solution that fixes the labels exactly below the respective columns.
Here is an image that shows what I want:

[image]

Comment: Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30509195/7214815) related to your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind each label's `minWidth` and `prefWidth` properties to the corresponding column's `width` property:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableWithLabelsBelowColumns extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Void> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getItems().add(null);

        TableColumn<Void, Void> firstNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        TableColumn<Void, Void> lastNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        TableColumn<Void, Void> emailColumn = new TableColumn<>("Email");
        table.getColumns().add(firstNameColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(lastNameColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(emailColumn);

        Label fnLabel = new Label("FN");
        Label lnLabel = new Label("LN");
        Label emailLabel = new Label("E");

        fnLabel.prefWidthProperty().bind(firstNameColumn.widthProperty());
        fnLabel.minWidthProperty().bind(firstNameColumn.widthProperty());
        lnLabel.prefWidthProperty().bind(lastNameColumn.widthProperty());
        lnLabel.minWidthProperty().bind(lastNameColumn.widthProperty());
        emailLabel.prefWidthProperty().bind(emailColumn.widthProperty());
        emailLabel.minWidthProperty().bind(emailColumn.widthProperty());

        HBox labels = new HBox(fnLabel, lnLabel, emailLabel);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        root.setBottom(labels);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

An alternative approach is to subclass `Pane` and override the `layoutChildren()` method to position the labels according to the widths of the columns. Register a listener to request layout on the pane with each column's width:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableWithLabelsBelowColumns extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Void> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getItems().add(null);

        TableColumn<Void, Void> firstNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        TableColumn<Void, Void> lastNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        TableColumn<Void, Void> emailColumn = new TableColumn<>("Email");
        table.getColumns().add(firstNameColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(lastNameColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(emailColumn);

        Label fnLabel = new Label("FN");
        Label lnLabel = new Label("LN");
        Label emailLabel = new Label("E");

        Pane labelPane = new Pane(fnLabel, lnLabel, emailLabel) {
            @Override
            protected void layoutChildren() {
                double fnWidth = firstNameColumn.getWidth();
                double fnHeight = fnLabel.prefHeight(fnWidth);
                fnLabel.resizeRelocate(0, 0, fnWidth, fnHeight);

                double lnWidth = lastNameColumn.getWidth();
                double lnHeight = lnLabel.prefHeight(lnWidth);
                lnLabel.resizeRelocate(fnWidth, 0, lnWidth, lnHeight);

                double emailWidth = emailColumn.getWidth();
                double emailHeight = emailLabel.prefHeight(emailWidth);
                emailLabel.resizeRelocate(fnWidth+lnWidth, 0, emailWidth, emailHeight);
            }
        };
        ChangeListener<? super Number> listener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> labelPane.requestLayout();
        firstNameColumn.widthProperty().addListener(listener);
        lastNameColumn.widthProperty().addListener(listener);
        emailColumn.widthProperty().addListener(listener);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        root.setBottom(labelPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just tried it, but it is not working when I try to use for 3rd and 4th column, especially the first solution. The second may work, I have to play a little bit with the numbers  `fnLabel.resizeRelocate(here, and her, fnWidth, fnHeight);`

Comment: At first was trying to use this solution :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506075/javafx-how-to-make-a-line-of-summationtotal-row-in-the-bottom-of-the-table/30509195#30509195, but the problem is that line is an Item of the table, so when I sort, filter, and so on it gets sorted, filtered.

Comment: Finally I solved it using your second suggestion, I have also added at first `.resizeRelocate()`  the width of the previous colums so it is working fine now. Thanks.