# Why does JavaFX not work under OpenJDK 17 from Homebrew?

Tags: java, javafx, homebrew, homebrew-cask, adoptopenjdk

After installing both the [OpenJDK](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/openjdk#default) and the [Temurin](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/temurin) casks (testing out first one, then the other), I'm still getting errors like these when running a simple example javafx app from the terminal:

```
Example.java:1: error: package javafx.application does not exist
```

It seems to me like JavaFX is not included in OpenJDK for macOS, at least the Homebrew versions, but it should be.

The version I'm installing is 17, on both counts.

What can I do to fix this? (I specifically don't want to install Oracle's JDK, to avoid hefty future licensing fees or potential litigation, which Oracle is known for.)

Comment: JavaFX is not included in the JDK since Java 9 (with the exception of the Azul JDK, IIRC). You need to include JavaFX on the class path yourself.

Comment: Read the [openjfx.io Getting Started documentation](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Comment: A complete, command-line example is cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69651076/230513).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Small clarification: JavaFX should be on the module path, not the class path, it can be run from the class path currently, and it works, but [it isn't supported that way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67854139/javafx-warning-unsupported-javafx-configuration-classes-were-loaded-from-unna).

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks, I didn't know that (I haven't actually used JavaFX myself).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaFX has never been an official part of the Java platform.

For a while, Oracle was bundling the JavaFX libraries with their own *Oracle JDK* product, but later stopped. Those libraries were a bonus, an extra, not required by the Java specifications.

Keep in mind that several vendors provide Java implementations. At least two of them provide a variant that includes the OpenJFX libraries implementing JavaFX, if that is what you want:

- *ZuluFX* by Azul Systems
- *LibericaFX* from BellSoft

Last time I looked, both of those products were available for macOS on both Intel Macs and Apple Silicon Macs.

Alternatively, you can bundle the OpenJFX libraries within your app.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks for letting me know. I read somewhere that JavaFX was BACK in JDK, but didn't get that they only meant the Oracle JDK. In any case, I'm including it now via Gradle and it works! :)